# Are there any current Macs capable of running NVIDIA based CUDA SDK?

Tags: hardware, macos

So I'm starting a new job, and seriously considering equipment purchases. I'd *like* to be able to have a Mac with NVIDIA GPU capable of developing CUDA-based code on it - it certainly wouldn't be running the code for performance, but it would be nice to be able to test the code to make sure it's even working.

But as I currently see it, there's no way to do that - the 15" Retina MBP has gone to an ATI-based graphics card, as has the 27" iMac and the Mac Pro, while everyone else is rocking integrated and/or Iris graphics cards.

Is there something about the line I'm missing?

Comment: How are you defining current?  From what I could find, the most current Mac that supports CUDA is the MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014 which has a GeForce GT 750M, which is on the Nvidia CUDA supported list.

Comment: @user3439894 Current = "Could buy a new, non-refurbished machine from Apple tomorrow". That laptop (which I own) is the best I could do as well, but I was rooting for me to be wrong

Comment: Then there is none.

Answer (score 1):

You could opt for an upgraded 6 or 12 core Intel Xeon 5690 3.46 GHz processor Mac Pro 5.1 and install a NVIDIA GTX 680 4GB graphics card running CUDA.

That can be done relatively cheap compared to the trashcan Mac Pro price tag, and it would do the job beautifully.